# Remove registry entry (which is not created by installer) during uninstallation (Inno Setup)

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup, setup-project

From the [Inno Setup Help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection):

> **dontcreatekey**
>
> When this flag is specified, Setup will not attempt to create the key or any value if the key did not already exist on the user's
>   system. No error message is displayed if the key does not exist.
>
> Typically this flag is used in combination with the `uninsdeletekey` flag, for deleting keys during uninstallation but not creating them
>   during installation.

My program creates a registry value (of type `string`) under the Current User autostart section, but only if the user explicitly does so from the settings screen.

I want that entry to be cleaned up by the uninstaller, so I added the following to my Inno Setup project:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "this_is_a_test"; Flags: dontcreatekey uninsdeletevalue
```

However that doesn't seem to work. I feel that the `dontcreatekey` flag only applies to "keys"¹ and not to "values". If so, how can I accomplish this?

(1) Assuming the "key" would be "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" (which will always exists prior to installation), and the "value" would be the entry of type `string` residing inside that key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ValueType: none`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=ValueType) or omit the `ValueType` parameter altogether:

> If `none` (the default setting) is specified, Setup will create the key but not a value. In this case the `ValueName` and `ValueData` parameters are ignored.

*Though note that the documentation is not completely correct. When combined with `uninsdeletevalue` flag, the `ValueName` is not ignored.*

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; \
    ValueType: none; ValueName: "this_is_a_test"; Flags: dontcreatekey uninsdeletevalue
```